# Design BottomNavigationView - set background color in code

Tags: android, android-support-library, bottomnavigationview

Is there any way to set the background color of the new design libraries `BottomNavigationView` in code to a custom color value instead of a color resource? Any "trick" maybe?

My current solution:

- I make the `BottomNavigationView` transparent
- I add a second view behind the `bottomNavigationView`
- I update this view's background

But this looks ugly, especially as I have to use a custom behaviour for the background view to be animated in parallel with the `BottomNavigationView` in the parent `CoordinatorLayout`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved it myself.

**Solution 1**

I just setup all items with a transparent background (this needs one resource file only) and then I theme the `BottomNavigationView` actual background itself.

```
bottomBar.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(color));
bottomBar.setItemBackgroundResource(R.drawable.transparent);
```

*Resource drawable - transparent.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

**Solution 2 - via reflection (support library 25.0.0)**

```
public void themeBottomBarBackgroundWithReflection(BottomNavigationView bottomBar, int color)
{
    try
    {
        Field mMenuViewField = BottomNavigationView.class.getDeclaredField("mMenuView");
        mMenuViewField.setAccessible(true);
        BottomNavigationMenuView mMenuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView)mMenuViewField.get(bottomBar);
        Field mButtonsField = BottomNavigationMenuView.class.getDeclaredField("mButtons");
        mButtonsField.setAccessible(true);
        BottomNavigationItemView[] mButtons = (BottomNavigationItemView[])mButtonsField.get(mMenuView);

        for (BottomNavigationItemView item : mButtons) {
            ViewCompat.setBackground(item, new ColorDrawable(color));
        }
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: In `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` you can not use `BottomNavigationView.class.getDeclaredField("mMenuView")` anymore, but you can reach the menuView in this way: `(BottomNavigationMenuView) getChildAt(0)`

Answer (score 0):

After many search, only this resolve my case:

```
bottomNavigationView.setItemBackground(new ColorDrawable(color));
```

Here I set each one of background item.